# WCF BasicHttpBinding - Where can I find SOAP1.1 in WSDL

Tags: wcf, soap, wsdl

I've been trying to find out which version of SOAP 1.1/1.2 being using in WSDL generated using WCF BasicHTTPBinding. But I've not been able to pin-point.

I need to confirm this so that I can tell me clients that we are using specific version of SOAP. The requirement is to use SOAP 1.1. From what I read BasicHttpBinding uses SOAP1.1 but not being able to find or check.

Could someone please help.
e.g.

```
<wsdl:definitions name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://mydomain.com" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://spotless.com/isb/services" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your WSDL definition WCF includes namespaces for both SOAP 1.1. and SOAP 1.2. Namespace for SOAP 1.1 has prefix `soap`. SOAP 1.1 endpoint will use only this namespace:

```
<wsdl:binding name="SomeBinding" type="...">
  <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" /> 
  <wsdl:operation name="GetTime">
    <soap:operation soapAction="..." style="..." /> 
    <wsdl:input name="...">
      <soap:body use="..." /> 
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="...">
      <soap:body use="..." /> 
    </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="...">
  <wsdl:port name="..." binding="tns:SomeBinding">
    <soap:address location="..." /> 
  </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:port>
```

Do you see all these elements prefixed by `soap`? That means SOAP 1.1 because `soap` prefix is defined for SOAP 1.1 namespace. If it uses `soap12` prefix instead it will mean SOAP 1.2.

If WCF service has multiple endpoints it will have multiple `wsdl:port` elements and each can refer to its own`wsdl:binding` specification with different version of SOAP and different policies (I skipped policy references in the example).

BasicHttpBinding in WCF always uses SOAP 1.1.

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav Mrnka, you are WCF genious. Thank you

Comment: This has not much to do with WCF itself - WSDL is interoperable way to describe services.